# Azure Data Factory - Copy Data - Failed to retrieve data

Tags: netsuite, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory - Copy Data activity from retrieving the data from NetSuite. It's all working fine for most of the tables except one large table which has around 800+ columns. Below are the errors that i'm facing in different places.

1. Unable to run Copy Data Activity - It fails with error "Failed to retrieve data" (I don't think it's a timeout issue as I set the timeout to 5 mins and it fails within 3 mins without even connecting to the source)
2. Within Copy Data - Unable to Import Schema - It fails with error "Failed to retrieve data"
3. Preview Data in Dataset - It fails with error "The operation has timed out"

Is there any limitation in the Data Factory in terms of the number of columns that you could have in the source? Please let me know

Thanks,
Praveen Sreeram

Comment: Hi Praveen, how are you connecting to netsuite? Via API?

Comment: Yes, We have an IR which has NetSuite ODBC drivers installed on it. It's not via API. I'm able to retrieve data from other tables from NetSuite. It's all working. The issue is only with the table which has 800+ fields in it.

Comment: I've worked with sources well over 1,000 columns, so I don't believe that is the issue. Perhaps it is a limitation with the Netsuite ODBC driver?

Comment: Here is a link to the limitations of data factory, but it doesnt mention a column limit. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/azure-data-factory-limits.md 

As Joel said, it may be an issue with the driver. Are you able to read the table with other software (or programming language) using the same driver?